# Is there a way to use a custom button to add a value for Aldeed: Autoform

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have a meteor application where I am using Aldeed: Autoform to directly insert a generated form into a database based off of a schema. Is there a way that I can use my own custom button or input field instead of using the options provided by autoform? I desire to do so because I need to have an onclick function take place when one of the buttons is clicked, but the autoform button is not a normal button and I cant add the onclick attribut.

When I say the options provided I mean this:

```
{{> afQuickField name='game'}}
```

and I want to replace that with this somehow:

```
<button id="makeLobBtn" class="button" type="button" onclick="div_show()">Make Lobby</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - you can use the [`{{#autoForm}}`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#autoform-1) component to do this:

```
{{#autoForm id="demo" schema=schema}}
  {{> afQuickFields}}
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
{{/autoForm}}
```